# installing cocoapods for firebase hangs and freeze

Tags: swift, git, firebase, cocoapods

recently I am having a problem that it seems to be unsolvable . I used to use pods for my swift projects and it worked well . Today , retried to use it for connecting to firebase and it seems like impossible . 
To tackle that , first , I fully removed cocoapods from my mac and then redownload the newest version .

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then ignorer to make sure it's fully downloaded I used this commands

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
```

and the result is

```
cocoapods (1.0.1)
cocoapods-core (1.0.1)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.0)
cocoapods-downloader (1.0.0)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.0.0)
cocoapods-try (1.0.0)
```

then I created a new Xcode project and called it "cocoapodsTesting" . Then I did all the steps mentioned in the firebase website till the one that I have to install pods on my project . 
so I went to my project directory ==> and wrote

```
pod init
```

then I opened the pod file and change the content to this :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'cocoapodsTesting' do
  pod ‘Firebase’
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for cocoapodsTesting

  target 'cocoapodsTestingTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'cocoapodsTestingUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

and then I used the command :

```
pod install
```

then this line appeared :

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
```

and then it it stayed the same for ever . Then I closed my terminal and re-opened it  and went to the same directory and used this command

```
pod repo remove master
```

then I get this :

```
[!] repo master does not exist

Usage:

    $ pod repo remove NAME

      Deletes the remote named `NAME` from the local spec-repos directory at
      `~/.cocoapods/repos/.`

Options:

    --silent    Show nothing
    --verbose   Show more debugging information
    --no-ansi   Show output without ANSI codes
    --help      Show help banner of specified command
```

then I go to "~/.cocoapods/repos/." there is a directory called master and nothing is inside .

and nothing happens .

***Please don't delete my post and don't mark it as repeated , I've gone through all the other questions and I couldn't make it workout . Please help me make this working***

Comment: try using `pod install --verbose`

Comment: here is the result   Preparing

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
  Cloning into 'master'...

Comment: what is your internet speed ?

Comment: It's not about my internet speed , I have tried this in different places but still the same results @Shubhank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `pod install`, then this line appeared as you can see:

   ```
   Setting up CocoaPods master repo
   ```
2. It may stay there for a long time.
3. You can `cd ~/.cocoapods`, then `du -sh *` every few seconds if you doubt whether it works.You will see the size is becoming larger.

   ```
   $ du -sh *
   9.7M    repos
   $ du -sh *
   14M     repos
   $ du -sh *
   20M     repos
   ```
4. Wait until the downloading is completed.Then it works normally.

For me, it is completed when

```
    $ du -sh *
    748M    repos
```